# How do I nest data from one Spark dataframe in another dataframe based on a condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes:

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((123, 2.23, 1.12), (234, 2.45, 0.12), (456, 1.112, 0.234))).toDF("objid", "ra", "dec")

val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((4567, 123, "name1", "val1"), (2322, 456, "name2", "val2"), (3324, 555, "name3", "val3"), (5556, 123, "name4", "val4"), (3345, 123, "name5", "val5"))).toDF("specid", "objid", "name", "value")
```

They look like below:

```
df1.show()

+-----+-----+-----+                                                             
|objid|   ra|  dec|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  123| 2.23| 1.12|
|  234| 2.45| 0.12|
|  456|1.112|0.234|
+-----+-----+-----+

df2.show()
+------+-----+-----+-----+
|specid|objid| name|value|
+------+-----+-----+-----+
|  4567|  123|name1| val1|
|  2322|  456|name2| val2|
|  3324|  555|name3| val3|
|  5556|  123|name4| val4|
|  3345|  123|name5| val5|
+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now I want to nest df2 inside df1 as a nested column so the schema should look like below:

```
val new_schema = df1.schema.add("specs", df2.schema)

new_schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(objid,IntegerType,false), StructField(ra,DoubleType,false), StructField(dec,DoubleType,false), StructField(specs,StructType(StructField(specid,IntegerType,false), StructField(objid,IntegerType,false), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true)),true))
```

The reason I wanted to do it this way was because there is a one to many relationship between df1 and df2, which means there are more than 1 specs per objid. And I am not going to join only these two tables. There are about 50 tables that I want to ultimately join together to create a mega table. Most of those tables have 1 to n relationships and I was just thinking about a way to avoid having a lot of duplicate rows and null cells in the ultimate join result.

The ultimate result would look something like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+----------------------+                                                              
|                 |          specs       |
|objid|   ra|  dec| specid| name  | value|
+-----+-----+-----+------+----+-------+  |
|  123| 2.23| 1.12| 4567  | name1 | val1 |
|                 | 5556  | name4 | val4 |
|                 | 3345  | name5 | val5 |
+-----+-----+-----+----------------------+
|  234| 2.45| 0.12|                      |
+-----+-----+-----+----------------------+
|  456|1.112|0.234| 2322  | name2 | val2 |
+-----+-----+-----+----------------------+
```

I was trying to add the column to df1 using `.withColumn` but ran into errors.

What I actually wanted to do was to select all the columns from df2 with the condition `where df2.objid = df1.objid` to match the rows and make that the new column in df1 but I am not sure if that's the best approach. Even if so, I am not sure how to do that.

Could someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: can you show the expected output in the above example? (i.e. make a artificial output of `show`). I suppose what you want is a simple `join`

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, **you cannot have dataframe inside another dataframe**(same is the case with RDDs).

What you need is a **join between two dataframes**. You can perform different types of joins and join the rows from two dataframes(this is where you make nest **df2 columns** inside df1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `join` both the dataframes based on the column `objid` like below

```
val join = df1.join(df2, "objid")
join.printSchema()
```

output:

```
root
 |-- objid: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- ra: double (nullable = false)
 |-- dec: double (nullable = false)
 |-- specid: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

and when we say

```
join.show()
```

the output will be

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
|objid|   ra|  dec|specid| name|value|
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
|  456|1.112|0.234|  2322|name2| val2|
|  123| 2.23| 1.12|  4567|name1| val1|
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
```

for more details you can check [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-joins.html)

### Update:

I think you are looking for something like this

```
df1.join(df2, df1("objid") === df2("objid"), "left_outer").show()
```

and the output is:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
|objid|   ra|  dec|specid|objid| name|value|
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
|  456|1.112|0.234|  2322|  456|name2| val2|
|  234| 2.45| 0.12|  null| null| null| null|
|  123| 2.23| 1.12|  4567|  123|name1| val1|
|  123| 2.23| 1.12|  5556|  123|name4| val4|
|  123| 2.23| 1.12|  3345|  123|name5| val5|
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Yeah simple join is okay but not quite what I wanted. I edited the question to give more details and the reason why I thought of doing it the way I mentioned.

Comment: @lloydh instead of editing the question, you should ask a new question with detailed description and share the link here in comment. Reverting the question to prev. version

Comment: @lloydh its always gud practice to create a new question instead of editing the existing one, I have updated the answer hopefully that will help

Comment: Yeah I understand, I just didn't want to sort of duplicate the same question because my edit wasn't a big deviation from the original question. Only a bit more details added to make it clearer. Thanks so much for your time and answer!

Comment: @lloydh if this answer solves your question, then accept the answer so that ppl will know that problem got resolved